# c++ vector of pointers push back in different way

Tags: c++, pointers

First we have a vector of pointers as:

```
vehicleGroup<vehicle*> VG;
```

In c++, is there a difference between:

```
VG.push_back(new vehicle(1));
VG.push_back(new vehicle(2));
```

and

```
//tmp_vehicle is a public class member
tmp_vehicle = new vehicle(1);
VG.push_back(tmp_vehicle);
tmp_vehicle = new vehicle(2);
VG.push_back(tmp_vehicle);
```

Does the vecotr VG contains the address of pointer itself OR the address the pointer pointed to?
What about map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VG contains exactly what you ask it for - pointers to vehicle objects.

When you call `push_back()`, it takes object you provided (in your case "object" is `vector*`), makes copy of it and puts it to vector. Vector uses internal memory chunk where it stores objects, so that's why it needs to make copies.

Answer (score 2):

The two versions do the same thing.

In your second version, `tmp_vehicle` first points to whatever `new vehicule(1)` returned. This pointer is then pushed into the vector, so the vector's first element now also points to that location.
Seen another way, you're not storing `tmp_vehicule` itself in the vector. You're storing a copy of that pointer.

Then you make `tmp_vehicule` point to something else. This doesn't change the fact that you stored a pointer to the first location in the vector. It changes what your variable points to, but doesn't change the vector in any way.

(And if you hadn't stored that pointer in the vector, you'd have a memory leak after the second assignment to `tmp_vector`, since you'd have lost all pointers to the first vehicule - so no way to delete it.)

Comment: So the vecotr VG contains the address the pointer pointed to instead of the address of pointer itself?

Comment: Yes, it stores a pointer to `vehicule`, not a pointer-to-pointer to `vehicule`.